# Replacing "||" Conditionals in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, higher-order-functions, or-operator, or-condition

Well, here goes my first stack overflow post!

Hello everyone, I have been learning a lot about functional programming recently. I found some older videos over at [funfunfunction](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiUqKm04-vgAhWtt1kKHToHCZ8QwqsBMAF6BAgFEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DBMUiFMZr7vk&usg=AOvVaw3ZRq0p-wFyXzv-kyACytAk) which whets my appetite and I've been playing around with them.

My question is… Is there a better/different/preferred way of refactoring this chunk of code:

```
if ( bodyClasses.contains("first-class") || bodyClasses.contains("second-class") || bodyClasses.contains("third-class") ) {
        pages.filter((page) => searchAndReplace( page.postType, ".selector" ));
}
```

I tried using `reduce()` but quickly learned I'd need to break the reduce prematurely as soon as the first iteration returned `true`. I feel like the if statement makes sense here but I'm just curious.

I know it is a small chunk of code without context, but the question is in regards *concept* and not *functionality*.

And to anyone that responds, I thank you in advance!

Comment: Not sure what .contains does exactly, but if it could take an array: `bodyClasses.contains(["first-class", "second-class","third-class"])`

Comment: What is `bodyClasses`?

Comment: @SpeedOfRound @chazsolo  `bodyClasses` is `document.querySelector("body").classList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get away the or, match against `.some` array values:

```
if(["first-class", "second-class", "third-class"].some(cls => bodyClasses.contains(cls)))
 /*...*/;
```

and I wouldn't use `.filter` if you are not doing anything with the returned values, then just use `.forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes down to it the `||` will likely need to be somewhere but maybe we can tuck them away. I like to use predicates in my if clauses to increase readability and create reusable functions.

```js
const hasSupport = classes =>
  classes.some(cls => cls === "class1" || cls === "class2" || cls === "class3");

if (hasSupport(bodyClasses)) { ... }
```

The last part to think about is inside your `if` statement. That filter will return a new list but you aren't storing the data anywhere. So, if you actually want a new list then store it in a variable:

```
const supportedPages = hasSupport(bodyClasses) 
  ?  pages.filter(...) 
  : []
```

If you instead want those side effects then use a forEach loop:

```
if (hasSupport(bodyClasses) { pages.forEach(...) }
```